# How to convert a imageview to bitmap image in Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I have an imageview.

```
  LoaderImageView image=new LoaderImageView(context,path1);
```

in above statement it returns a imageview. So I want to convert it into a bitmap. How can I convert imageview into bitmap image.

```
   ImageView i=new ImageView(context);
   i.setImageBitmap(convertimagetobitmap);
```

In above statement I have set a bitmap image (converted image) to another imageview.

Comment: I am not sure what you are wanting to do. :-?

Comment: i want to do set an image in gridview

Comment: what is LoaderImageView?it is class extending imageview ot other?.pls describe

Comment: in above i paste the code of LoaderImageView class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look this code:

```
// i is an imageview which you want to convert in bitmap
Bitmap viewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(i.getWidth(),i.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(viewBitmap);

i.draw(canvas);
```

That's it, your imageview is stored in bitmap viewBitMap.

Comment: i want change image to bitmap image not i.

Comment: what i cant understand?i is imageview

Comment: LoaderImageView returns a imageview(image).i want to convert a that imageview to bitmap image and then set it to gridview image(i).

Comment: so this code is same for just use your imageview name instead of i

Comment: use this link for grideview:http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Comment: already i tried that one, every thing is correct .but i.setImageBitmap(bitmap bm) accepts only bitmap image.but in my code the image is LoaderImageView .so i want to convert it into a bitmap image like    Bitmap bitmap=................... and then i want to set it to gridview image like a i.setImageBitmap(bitmap).

Comment: it shows an error . this is the error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0

Comment: buddy you have set the imageview i as return value of ur method which returning imageview

Comment: pls edit ur answer with currend code impl. and describe whr exactly error comes

Comment: the LoaderImageView image has width and height as zero

Answer (score 0):

Look at:

```
ImageView.getDrawingCache();
```

But you have to keep in mind that returned `Bitmap` won't be the same as you get from resource or file, since `Bitmap` will depend on display physical properties (resolution, scaling, color deepness and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Check this [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html)
This gets you access to bitmap where view is stored [DrawingCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache%28boolean%29) (cash has to be turned on)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**This will work :**

```
ImageView img;
img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap scaledBitmap = img.getDrawingCache();
```

//Store to tmp file

```
        String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File mFolder = new File(extr + "/tmpfolder");
        if (!mFolder.exists()) {
            mFolder.mkdir();
        }

        String s = "tmp.png";

        File f = new File(mFolder.getAbsolutePath(), s);

        strMyImagePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 70, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        scaledBitmap.recycle();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
    }
```